# Android Device device shows Unknown (?????) in eclipse

Tags: android

I have a local device that has an android version 4.1. When I'm start running my app with my real device its show ????? like the image below. But when I connected it to other computer it works fine. So I guess my adb has the problem because my device work fine in other computer. Here are the list that I tried.

```
1. Uncheck and Check usb debugging in my phone.
2.adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
adb devices
```

Note: I'm using Linux Ubuntu.
I tried other devices(Samsung Galaxy) and it works fine.

Any thoughts will be highly appreciated.[image: Here are what my eclipse shows]

Comment: You have to set read/write permissions for that USB device. I don't remember the details, but there was a good reply on SO already.

Comment: It could also be something as trivial as a bad USB port on your computer - try another port. Also if you have another device, try to plug that in to see if ADB can't see that one as well...

Comment: yes I tried 2 Samsung devices and it detected fine.

Comment: Which device are you using?

Comment: Its a local brand here in our Country (MyPhone) it has 4.1 android version

Comment: This is the problem, most likely does not even have to vendor id... This problem will disappear if use Windows or Mac OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add vendor ID to android.rules file. 
Please follow this link to know about particular vendor id & how to do this.

```
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html
```

Comment: My device is not on the list. But can you guide me how to add vendor ID using terminal in ubuntu?

Comment: Open provided link & follow 3 step onwards , these commands will be entered through terminal.

Comment: I can't follow the steps because I'm new in using ubuntu.

Comment: Follow this link ... to know basic of ubuntu terminal.. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal